# Service Fabric: packaging code error: missing required references

Tags: azure, reference, package, microservices, azure-service-fabric

After updating SF I've got an issue that prevents using of SF totally, I'll try to put a problem in words without code.

Service fabric application `AppName.SF` consists of an `AppName.SF.StatefulActor` and `AppName.SF.StatefulService`. Both reference to class library called `AppName.Core`.

**Case 1:** `StatefulActor` not references `StatefulService` - package performs OK:

`AppName.SF\pkg\Debug\AppName.SF.StatefulActor\Code has` `AppName.Core.dll`

`AppName.SF\pkg\Debug\AppName.SF.StatefulService\Code` has `AppName.Core.dll`

each package Code folder has `AppName.Core.dll`. Deployment performs successfully.

**Case 2:** `StatefulActor` references `StatefulService` - package performs BAD:

`AppName.SF\pkg\Debug\AppName.SF.StatefulActor\Code` has `AppName.Core.dll`

`AppName.SF\pkg\Debug\AppName.SF.StatefulService\Code` has **no(!)** `AppName.Core.dll`

So I get a missing reference error if I try to deploy application in cluster. Issue appeared after SF updated to 1.4.87-preview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a workaround add the following to your application project (.sfproj) file:

```
<Target Name="CopyExtraPackageFiles" AfterTargets="Package">
    <Copy SourceFiles="..\AppName.Core\bin\$(Configuration)\AppName.Core.dll"
          DestinationFolder="pkg\$(Configuration)\AppName.SF.StatefulService\Code" />
</Target>
```

This makes some assumptions about the location of your AppName.Core project.  Adjust the path if necessary.

This will manually copy AppName.Core.dll to the appropriate location in the package where it is missing.

**EDIT:**
Or try this for a general purpose workaround instead of the above code snippet.  Let me know if it works.

```
<Target Name="EnsureProjectReferencesAreConfigured" BeforeTargets="GetCopyToOutputDirectoryItems">
  <MSBuild
      Condition=" '@(ServiceProjectReference)' != '' "
      Projects="@(ServiceProjectReference)"
      Targets="AssignProjectConfiguration"
      Properties="Configuration=$(Configuration);Platform=$(Platform)" />
</Target>
```

Comment: Thanks. In real solution there are too many referenced dlls. When can the fix be expected? Whether to wait for the next major update?

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you've found a bug - we are investigating. In the interim, it should work if you build using msbuild.

Comment: Could you please explain how exactly can I use msbuild to fix the problem?

Comment: You can use `msbuild.exe /t:package myapp.sfproj` to package.

Comment: Thanks, it helped. I've used MSBuild to package and then manually executed `Deploy-FabricApplication.ps1`. Is there a way to attach a debugger to SF application just like if I press Start button in VS?

Comment: Not exactly. F5 has the smarts to attach to every service on every node. You can manually attach the debugger, but it will be just to a single service on a single node.